# Why my site is getting blocked and getting categorized as "proxy avoidance"

Tags: proxy

i created a website in my spare time and when i try to access it from work its getting blocked and the reason corporate firewall giving is 
"proxy avoidance" Sites that provide information on how to bypass proxy server features or gain access to URLs in any way that bypasses the proxy server.

What i can do to access the site and make it safe so it doesnt get blocked by corporate firewall?

i am using jquery plugins and simple html and css.

Comment: Corporate firewalls often block sites for obscure reasons or based on outdated IP lists. The easiest thing to do is compile a list of reasonable web sites that are blocked, put yours in there, and ask them to unblock them all.

Comment: Could there be keywords which are triggering the block?

Comment: Have you asked your IT department? The people actually responsible for that firewall...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your site isn't designed to bypass proxies, Perhaps somebody else is hosting a proxy server on the same IP as your site (shared hosting?)

Comment: i use godaddy as host, and on the same domain i have another site which works fine, infact this site is just a redesign of the previous site.